# I can send email but, I can't receive mail

Tags: email

I can send email, but I can't receive email.  No error messages. Just nothing in the "In box".  Can anybody helpme fix this problem?

Comment: You should explain what your problem is in more detail! Is it a problem with your email client or are you running a server that is supposed to send/receive emails?

Comment: Which email client are you using (eg: Thunderbird, or webmail like Gmail's online interface)? Which email provider are you using (eg: Yahoo!)?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are new to using Ubuntu and perhaps have just installed it on your pc?

Perhaps then you are using the pre installed email programme called Thunderbird. If not please let us know what version of Ubuntu you are using and what is the name of your email application.

1 If you are using Thunderbird there is a guide here on how to set up your incoming mail either manually

[Thunderbird automatic setup](https://support.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/kb/automatic-account-configuration)

or if you have a special or difficult email account you can follow this guide again from Thunderbird which will guide you to manually configuring your email.

[Manually setting up your thunderbird email.](https://support.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/kb/manual-account-configuration)

There is also a quite nice guide here to using Thunderbird in Ubuntu

[Ubuntu and Thunderbird](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Thunderbird)

If you get stuck tell us here about who your email provider is  (Hotmail/Google/Yahoo etc) and we will be better placed to help you.

Don't worry it will be fixable with a few attempts using the guides above. I used to find it a nightmare to set up Thunderbird but it was often really small mistakes I had made which broke it.

Good luck and let us know how you get on.